# Page navigation setup, carousel with vertical scroll new content top

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a carousel a-like page navigation with horizontal animation in and out of the page content, the content on the page has vertical scroll.

My problem is:
If I scroll down the page and change page with a horizontal animation the new 'content box' sliding in is affected by the global scroll but I would like the new content sliding in with the top of it's content snapped to the bottom of the menu. So your at the top of that page.

example http://goo.gl/DMCS0T

Comment: Please provide code, or a fiddle, it's really hard to answer a question like this..

Comment: http://goo.gl/DMCS0T check this little example out, this would illustrate what i'm talking about